# CSRF attack to create USER

Tags: wp-admin, users, forms, security, nonce

I'm looking for to fix the issue below :

The following scenario show a successful CSRF attack resulting in the creation of a new user on wordpress:

1. The attacker sends malicious html page to an application user using social engineering techniques.
2. User executes the html page and the code embedded in the page instructs the user s browser to generate a new user creation request.

website.com/wp-admin/user-new.php

3. The attacker successfully creates a new application user.

This is the begin for the source code of the form to create user :

[image]

Comment: this cannot append because the value of "nonce" is only provided at the connected user. then the attacker cannot guess it and he will not be able to create a user.

Comment: This won't work as you expect, but if it did, this would be considered irresponsible disclosure of a security hole. If you find a security hole in WP, report it via the official channels discretely so that it can be fixed before it's exploited

Comment: It won't work since a valid nonce is required, but if you feel vulnerable you can block all external POST request  in htaccess

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to block external post request about create user form (user-new.php)?